# Integromat/Make: Rename Google Sheet (individual sheet vs entire spreadsheet)

Tags: google-sheets-api, make.com, integromat-apps

I'm working with Integromat (now Make) and am wanting to rename an individual sheet in a Google Spreadsheet. How can I do this?

Integromat has a number of similar/related options for Google Sheets:

- Create a Spreadsheet
- Add a Sheet

But neither allows me to update the name of an existing sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integromat/Make also has an option **Make an API Call** for Google Sheets.

The [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) has an HTTP request method for updating properties of spreadsheets, including [UpdateSheetPropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatesheetpropertiesrequest) which is used to update the properties of an individual sheet, specified by the sheet ID. Using this and the [SheetProperties object](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#sheetproperties) we can update the name of an individual sheet via Integromat as follows:

In Integromat:

1. Add Google Sheets module **Make an API Call**
2. In the URL field enter spreadsheets/your-spreadsheet-id:batchUpdate
3. Set the method to POST
4. In the Body field, enter:

```
     {
        "requests": [{
            "updateSheetProperties": {
                "properties": {
                    "sheetId": "id-of-the-individual-sheet-to-be-updated",
                    "title": "your new sheet name"
                },
                "fields": "title"
            }
        }]
    }
```